# Copy data from unread email and mark as read

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I want to copy "Unread emails" from Outlook RSS feeds to Excel. Those copied emails should be marked as "Read" in Outlook.

The code below returns

> Invalid procedure call or argument.

```vb
Private Sub run_btn_Click()
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
    Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim OutlookMail As Variant

    Dim i As Integer

    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olfolderrssfeeds).Folders("Folder Name")

    If Folder.items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True").Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Unread email", vbInformation, "Congratulation!"
    End If

    i = 1

    For Each OutlookMail In Folder.items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")
        Range("eMail_subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = Left(OutlookMail.Subject, 11)
        Range("eMail_date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("eMail_text").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body        
        i = i + 1
    Next OutlookMail

    If Folder.items.Restrict("[Unread] = True") Then
        Folder.items.UnRead = False
        Folder.items.Save
    End If

    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Where exactly does the debugger stop?

Comment: Is there actually a folder called "Folder Name"?  Also, should the last Restrict call be testing Restrict.Count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce the exact error you saw, and I don't know where the error was.  However, the following works for me, run from Excel 2013 to control Outlook 2013.  See `<==` marks.

```
Option Explicit    ' <== Always include this at the top of every module

Private Sub run_btn_Click()
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
    Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim OutlookMail As Object   ' <== Doesn't need to be Variant

    Dim rowIndex As Integer     ' <== rename from `i` to `rowIndex` for clarity

    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderRssFeeds)        ' <==
        ' After you call GetDefaultFolder, you already have a folder - you don't
        ' need to call .Folder() on it.

    If Folder.UnReadItemCount = 0 Then      ' <== Don't need to use Restrict for unread-item count
        MsgBox "No Unread email", vbInformation, "Congratulation!"
    End If

    rowIndex = 1

    For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")
        Range("eMail_subject").Offset(rowIndex, 0).Value = Left(OutlookMail.Subject, 11)
        Range("eMail_date").Offset(rowIndex, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("eMail_text").Offset(rowIndex, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body

        MarkItemReadIfEmail OutlookMail     ' <== Mark each one read as it's processed

        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
    Next OutlookMail

    'If Folder.UnReadItemCount > 0 Then     ' <== already did this in the loop above
    '    Folder.Items.UnRead = False        '     so don't need to do it here.
    '    Folder.Items.Save
    'End If

    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub MarkItemReadIfEmail(obj As Object)
    Dim mail As PostItem    ' **Edit** - was originally MailItem

    ' Find out if it's a mail item
    Set mail = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set mail = obj
    On Error GoTo 0

    If mail Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' It's an email, so mark it.
    mail.UnRead = False
    mail.Save
End Sub
```

`Sub MarkItemReadIfEmail` is a careful way of marking emails read.  I actually don't know enough about the Outlook object model to know that `Folder.Items` always returns a **edit** `PostItem` for RSS-feed folders.  Therefore, before treating each item as a `PostItem`, I check whether it actually is one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and modification! for [Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderRssFeeds)], I have two folders in RSS Feeds so that I have to keep .Folders(). However, the emails are still shown as "Unread" without any error message popped up from Excel, I am not sure is it because I am using Outlook and Excel 2016...

Comment: @QuincyChan strange!  If you stick a breakpoint on the `If mail Is Nothing ...` line, what are the types of `obj` and `mail`?  (You can Add Watch for each, and the Type column in the Watch window will show you.)  Maybe they are not `MailItem`s, in which case the `UnRead=False` line would never run.  The fix is to change `MailItem` in `Dim mail As MailItem` to the type of `obj`.

Comment: @QuincyChan Try changing `MailItem` to `PostItem` and see what happens.  I found [this forum thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/de270997-75cd-4dd2-9ff5-e8ca11940437/rss-feed-in-outlook?forum=vsto) that says RSS-feed items are `PostItem` instances.

Comment: @cxwStrange.......I have 13 unread RSS-feed but only 7 of them were exported to excel and marked as read in Outlook....6 unread remaining in Outlook....

Comment: @QuincyChan so the 6 are probably not `PostItem` instances.  Use the Watch window to see what they are, and then add those options to `MarkItemReadIfEmail` or a copy of it.  Alternatively, you can change `PostItem` to `Object`, but then you will get an error any time you hit an item that doesn't support both `UnRead` and `Save`.  If you still have trouble, please ask a new question, linking to this one and showing your latest code.  Maybe someone with more Outlook experience will have additional ideas.  Good luck!